# C++ Concurrent Queue memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Consider the following program, which implements a SINGLE consumer, MULTIPLE producer concurrent queue.

Runs fine in the context of 1 consumer, 1 producer.

However, putting up a second consumer (un-commenting the lines below) results in memory leaks and I can't understand why...

Using Queue's T=std::shared_ptr, and modifying pop to return a shared_ptr fixes the memory leak, so what am I missing in the code as it is below?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

template<typename T>
class Queue {
private:
    static constexpr unsigned mSize = 256;  //power of two only
    static constexpr unsigned mRoundRobinMask = mSize - 1;

    static const T mEmpty;

    T mData[mSize];
    std::mutex mtx;
    unsigned mReadP = 0;
    unsigned mWriteP = 0;

public:
    const T pop() {    
        if (!peek()) {
            return mEmpty; // copy
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);   

        T& ret = mData[mReadP & mRoundRobinMask]; // get a ref

        mReadP++;
        return ret; // copy of ref
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) {
        start:
        if (!wait()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("!Queue FULL!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        if(size() == mSize) {
            goto start;
        }

        mData[mWriteP & mRoundRobinMask] = aItemRef;
        mWriteP++;
    }

    bool peek() const {
        return mWriteP != mReadP;
    }

    unsigned size() const {
        return mWriteP > mReadP ? mWriteP - mReadP : mReadP - mWriteP; // mod (Read-Write)
    }

    bool wait() {
        unsigned it = 0;
        while (size() == mSize) {
            if (it++ > 1000000) { return false; }
        }

        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T>
const T Queue<T>::mEmpty = T{ };

int main(int, char**) {
    using Method = std::function<void()>;

    Queue<Method*> queue;

    std::thread consumer([ & ] {
        while (true) {
            if (queue.peek()) {
                auto task = queue.pop();
                (*task)();
                delete task;
            }
        }
    });

    std::thread producer1([ & ] {
        unsigned index = 0;
        while (true) {
            auto id = index++;
            auto task = new Method([ = ] {
                std::cout << "Running task " << id << std::endl;
            });
            queue.push(task);
        }
    });

    // std::thread producer2 ([ & ] {
    //     unsigned index = 0;
    //     while (true) {
    //         auto id = index++;
    //         auto task = new Method([ = ] {
    //             std::cout << "Running task " << id<< std::endl;
    //         });
    //         queue.push(task);
    //     }
    // });

    consumer.join();
    producer1.join();
    // producer2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Suggested edit of push method by @1201ProgramAlarm

```
    void push(const T& aItemRef) {
        start:
        if (!wait()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("!Queue FULL!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        if(getCount() == mSize) {
            goto start;
        }

        mData[mWriteP & mRoundRobinMask] = aItemRef;
        mWriteP++;
    }
```

Does the job, no more leaks, but that GOTO :( :(....any idea on how to avoid using goto?

Comment: Somebody's downvoted and voted closed because he she they wants debugging details. Did you debug this? P.s. shared_ptr is not thread safe, but that's a different issue

Comment: Running it with 1 consumer, 1 producer has no memory leaks and runs fine for hours, doesn't break. How am I to debug?

It only breaks with 2 producers, and when I run out of RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your example.

The main thing is that it's not thread-safe: Both `push()` and `pop()` modify non-atomic member variables `mReadP` and `mWriteP` while not protected by a `mutex`.

A second, less important issue is that waiting on the arrival of items to pop or free space to push is typically done by using [condition_variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), which suspend a thread until a condition is reached.

Please try the version below, as I updated it with these changes.

I also added a termination condition, to show how to get all threads out safely and slowed the whole thing down to show what's happening.

```
#include <array>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
class Queue {
private:
    static constexpr unsigned mSize = 256;  //power of two only
    static constexpr unsigned mRoundRobinMask = mSize - 1;

    std::array<T, mSize> mData;
    std::mutex mtx;
    unsigned mReadP = 0;
    unsigned mWriteP = 0;

    std::condition_variable notFull;
    std::condition_variable notEmpty;

    bool stopped = false;

public:
    const std::optional<T> pop() {
        // Always grab the mutex before accessing any shared members
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // Wait until there is an item in the queue.
        notEmpty.wait(lock, [&] {return stopped || mWriteP != mReadP; });
        if(stopped)
            return std::nullopt;

        T& ret = mData[mReadP & mRoundRobinMask]; // get a ref
        mReadP++;

        // Wake any threads waiting on full buffer
        notFull.notify_one();
        return ret; // copy of ref
    }

    void push(const T& pItem) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // Wait until there is space to put at least one item
        notFull.wait(lock, [&] { return stopped || getCount() < mSize; });
        if(stopped)
            return;

        mData[mWriteP & mRoundRobinMask] = pItem;
        mWriteP++;

        // Wake any threads waiting on empty buffer
        notEmpty.notify_one();
    }

    unsigned getCount() const {
        return mWriteP > mReadP ?
            mWriteP - mReadP : mReadP - mWriteP; // mod (Read-Write)
    }

    void stop() {
        // Signal the stop condition
        stopped = true;

        // Grabbing the lock before notifying is essential to make sure
        // any worker threads waiting on the condition_variables.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // Wake all waiting threads
        notFull.notify_all();
        notEmpty.notify_all();
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    using Method = std::function<void()>;

    Queue<Method> queue;
    bool running = true;

    std::thread consumer([ & ] {
        while (running) {
            auto task = queue.pop();
            if(task) {
                // If there was a task, execute it.
                (*task)();
            } else {
                // No task means we are done.
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    std::thread producer1([ & ] {
        unsigned index = 0;
        while (running) {
            auto id = index++;
            queue.push([ = ] {
                std::cout << "Running task " << id << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            });
        }
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    // Use pre-c++-20 mechanisms to signal the worker threads to stop their loops
    running = false;
    // If they're in the queue stop that too.
    queue.stop();

    consumer.join();
    producer1.join();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that if you can use `C++20` you totally should, since it has [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) which has more elegant mechanisms like automatic thread joining and `condition_variable::wait()` termination through [std::jthread::request_stop()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop).

Answer (score 1):

Your `push` is not thread safe.

When called by two threads when there is only one slot available in the queue, both threads can pass `wait`, resulting in the possibility that one of the threads will overwrite an existing element in the queue. That overwritten element will not be freed, resulting in the memory leak.

The solution is the check if the queue is full again *after* getting the lock. If it is, you need to free the lock and wait again until a slot is available.

As an aside, the `wait` function can be made friendlier by including a `sleep(0)` call in the while loop. This will reduce the power consumption and use of CPU resources while waiting.